# Grid search: Get index that corresponds best to value (for a whole matrix)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I know that this question party has been answered, but I am looking specifically at numpy and scipy. Say I have a grid

```
lGrid = linspace(0.1, 8, 50)
```

and I want to find the index that corresponds best to `2`, I do

```
index = abs(lGrid-2).argmin()
lGrid[index]
2.034
```

However, what if I have a whole matrix of values instead of `2` here. I guess iteration is pretty slow. `abs(lGrid-[2,4])` however will fail due to shape issues. I will need a solution that is easily extendable to N-dim matrices. What is the best course of action in this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcasting:

```
from numpy import arange,linspace,argmin
vals = arange(30).reshape(2,5,3) #your N-dimensional input, like array([2,4])
lGrid = linspace(0.1, 8, 50)
result = argmin(abs(lGrid-vals[...,newaxis]),axis=-1)
```

for example, with input `vals = array([2,4])`, you obtain `result = array([12, 24])` and `lGrid[result]=array([ 2.03469388,  3.96938776])`

Answer (score 1):

You "guess that Iteration is pretty slow", but I guess it isn't.   So I would just just iterate over the "whole Matrix of values instead of `2`".   Perhaps:

```
 for val in BigArray.flatten():
    index = abs(lGrid-val).argmin()
    yield lGrid[index]
```

If `lGrid` is failry large, then the overhead of iterating in a Python `for` loop is probably not big in comparison to the vecotirsed operation Happening inside it.

There might be a way you can use broadcasting and reshaping to do the whole thing in one giant operation, but would be complicated, and you might accidentally allocate such a huge array that your machine slows down to a crawl.

Comment: This is part of a value-function iteration. The matrix here will by more or less `20`x`50`x`3`. However, I will iterate over this code 500-1000 times (or so). So I'm under the impression that the matrix size is "small" while the overhead is rather big - but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Anyhow, you may want to replace `2` with `val` in your code. Also, how is `yield` to be understood? Adding the overhead of a function is not really necessary, is it?

Comment: I have replaced the 2.  `yield` means that if the code above were defined in a function, then that function would return an iterator over your return values.  It's a clean method if your result should be a flat list, although again it is normal python, and much slower than returning an array.